# Copy values from one field to another within a subset

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a query but I'm stuck.

**Context**
On my website users have different fields on their profile. One of these fields is a checkbox for the newsletter. Now we are going to make a second newsletter. Every user that is subscribed to the newsletter will be automatically subscribed to the second and have the option to unsubscribe. The user that are not subscribed for the original newsletter should not receive the second newsletter either.

**Table**
The fields are stored in a table "Profile_field". This table has 3 columns

- fid => field Id (this can be profile name, address, newsletter, ...)
- uid => user Id
- value

So for every user I need to copy the value of field1 to field2

**The query so far**

```
UPDATE profile_values AS copy
SET value =
   (SELECT value
    FROM ( Select Value
           FROM profile_values as original
           WHERE fid = 12
         ) AS temp
   )
WHERE fid=37
;
```

Now this gives me the error:

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

I understand why I have this. It's because in my subquery I don't take into account that a field returns multiple results because of the different users. In other words I don't take the user into account.

So I tried something like

```
FROM ( Select Value
           FROM profile_values as original
           WHERE fid = 12
         ) AS temp
WHERE uid=copy.uid
```

But that doesn't work either.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '"temp" WHERE uid=copy.uid )where fid=37' at line 1

So how can I take the user into account in my query?

Warm regards

Stephan Celis

Comment: I suggest redesigning your db to take into account that you have a many to many relationship between users and subscriptions.

Comment: It's made this way by an old Drupal installation so I can't. If it wasn't I would agree with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the update I would use:

```
UPDATE profile_values pv
       JOIN (SELECT value,
                    uid
             FROM   profile_values
             WHERE  fid = 12) AS current_field_values
         ON current_field_values.uid = pv.uid
SET    pv.value = current_field_values.value
WHERE  pv.fid = 37
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with *adding* a newsletter, then I would expect an `insert` rather than an `update`.  Something along the lines of:

```
insert into profile_values(uid, fid, value)
    select uid, 37, 1
    from profile_values pv
    group by uid
    having max(fid = 12 and value = 1) > 0;
```

That is, insert a new value for the new newsletter, for all users that have the existing one.

Comment: I will need both the update and the insert. For some reason started with the update.

Comment: @StephanCelis . . . For the problem you describe, I don't see where an update fits in.

Comment: Because between me adding the field (in a form of drupal) and executing the query some user may have pressed the 'save' button on his profile or created a new profile. In that scenario the value would be 0 instead of 1 in some cases.